# Why does casting a string as an integer not work?

Tags: php, casting, int

***// EDIT:*** The end goal is to detect whether user-submitted value is a string, or an integer. Because the value is obtained from form input, it is cast as string even when the value provided is an integer number.

I am performing a simple comparison to detect if a string variable is equal to its integer value. The value is passed from an HTML form field.

When the string value is a single letter, it evaluates to true, when it should not.

```
if ( ($val == (int)$val ) && strlen( $val ) == strlen( (int)$val ) ){
}
```

I've also tried using `intval()` rather than casting int variable type.

It is always evaluating as true. But `r` does not == `0`, so how can this be?

```
$val = 'r'; 
echo 'Does $val = (int)$val? ' . ($val == (int)$val);

echo '<br/><br/>';
echo '$val was: ' . $val . '<br/>';
echo '(int)$val was: ' . (int)$val;
```

Output:

```
Does $val = (int)$val? 1

$val was: r
(int)$val was: 0
```

Comment: when you compare with `==`, values are _implicitely_ cast. it's the same as `(int)$val == (int)$val`. thing is: what are you even trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks for this. User can pass a record ID (integer) or a name (string). I build a MySQL query depending on whether it's integer (`user_id = $val`) or whether it's string (`user_name` LIKE '%val%'`)

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't `($val == (int)$val)` be `($val = (int)$val)` ? or are you trying to use a ternary operator here?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm not setting variable value, nor ternary operator. Just simple comparison.

Comment: I use `if (is_numeric($searchval))` when I do a string or ID entry search.

Comment: @PatrickMoore use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) for this.

Comment: Thanks guys, did not know of `is_numeric()`!

Comment: @PatrickMoore there - i gave you an answer which you may accept ;) plus: include in your questions what you are trying to _achieve_, not just what you are trying to do. often one tries to find over-complicated problems because they're not fully aware of the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if your string is actually a number (which is what you want according to your comments), you don't have to hack together some custom test. PHP provides a built-in function for this:

```
if(is_numeric($val)) {
    //do integer stuff
} else {
    //do string stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To check whether string is actually a number, I'd use something like that:

```
if (strval(intval($val, 10)) == $val)
```

Note: this will detect only strings with integer numbers, there is also `is_numeric` which works for decimal and exponential (like `+0123.45e6`).

Note 2: `is_int` detects actual type of variable, so for `"123"` it will return false because it is string.

Note 3: you could have problems when number is submitted with `+` prefix like `+123` - it is up to you whether you want to support such case or not

Comment: why reinvent the wheel when there is a built-in function `is_numeric()`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann because is_numeric also detect decimal and exponential numbers, but here we need only integers (If I got OP correctly)

Comment: @IncredibleHat because is_int detect type of variable, so for "123" it will return false, as type is string, not int